# "ctags: Unknown option: --output-format" error

Tags: ctags

On macOS, getting the error while running this command:

`ctags -R --output-format=json --languages=ruby --exclude=.git --exclude=log . $(bundle list --paths) -f .tags`

per advice here: https://www.boost.co.nz/blog/2018/01/improving-ruby-rails-debugging-ctags

It appears to be a valid command option: https://docs.ctags.io/en/latest/output-format.html

So I'm not sure why I'm getting an error.

**UPDATE:**
OK, that blog article has ctags installed from HEAD formula. So I installed that version but now I get a different error:

`ctags: unknown output format name supplied for "output-format=json"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the same article and got the same error. The problem is the suggested command:

```
brew install --HEAD universal-ctags/universal-ctags/universal-ctags
```

This doesn't build `universal-ctags` with `libjansson` and as Masatake YAMATO suggested, `libjansson` is needed to use `--output-format=json`.

Try installing `universal-ctags` with the `--with-jansson` flag:

```
brew install --HEAD --with-jansson universal-ctags/universal-ctags/universal-ctags
```

Also, to avoid the `ctags: -f option may not follow a file name` error, move `-f .tags` before `. $(bundle list --paths)`:

```
ctags -R --output-format=json --languages=ruby --exclude=.git --exclude=log -f .tags . $(bundle list --paths)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use json output only when you built the ctags executable with libjansson library.

If you built the ctags executable with libjansson, you will see "json" in --list-features output like:

```
$ universal-ctags --list-features
#NAME             DESCRIPTION
iconv             can convert input/output encodings
interactive       accepts source code from stdin
json              supports json format output
...
```

If you don't find "json", you must rebuild the ctags executable with libjansson library.
If you find "json", but the option, --output-format=json, doesn't work, it will be a bug. I recommend you to report it to https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/issues though fixing it is not promised.

Comment: For anyone looking for performing this rebuild, check out the steps here: https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/issues/2013#issuecomment-465761032